# JS extension to highlight text in Alfresco document

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

When a document is opened, I want to accomplish the ajax-request with document text, get response and highlight words in document, which are specified in the response.

Is it possible to accomplish through Alfresco API?

So I just want to know: is it possible to inject my javascript code to document page and how to do that in Alfresco 5.2?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to highlight the text in the document preview ?

Comment: @MarcoAltieri, it looks like preview: https://i.imgur.com/XXw6tn0.png

Comment: From where search results are coming from advance search page or from Site search or from Search Bar in Right Up corner?

Comment: @vikash, words with yellow background are not search result, they should be highlighted by my js according to my server response. so the question is: can I get document text and highlight some words or wrap in some divs by alfresco api? or do I need to use setTimeouts to find out when div with content is ready and other workaroundly stuff?

Comment: Have you got your solution ?

Comment: @vikash I've added dependency to tomcat config, so injected my js.

Comment: Ok,are you able to highlight text?

Comment: yes, I did that after I've got the injection :)

Answer (score 2):

This is my gitlab [project](https://gitlab.com/vikash.patel/highlight-text-search) to highlight searched text from Site Search dashlet and from advance search page. 
Please override `<alf_home>\tomcat\webapps\share\components\preview\PdfJs.js` this file with [PdfJs-highlight-query.js](https://gitlab.com/vikash.patel/highlight-text-search/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/components/preview/PdfJs-highlight-query.js)

What is does if url contains query parameter like this
http://localhost:8081/share/page/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/10df24c1-8f2e-4f76-ab52-33b85fe6e26d&query=abc

Then if the following document contains **abc** then all the abc text will get hilighted

> Alfresco have functionality to inline search text from within the
>   repository documents and search the text from a document and 
>   highlight the all available text from within the document .
>
> So for that you need to first search your document and you have to
>   make manually search for the required text in the document .
>
> What we have implemented is that you have to search for the required
>   document and list of results will appear and after clicking on the
>   document , document details page will get open and the all searched
>   text will get highlighted within the document previewer.
>
> This will remove your extra required click and enter search text
>   again.
>
> Click on search results and document details page will get open and
>   will highlight the document previewer within available document text.